# How to call different object classes in main class constructor based on different conditions?

Tags: java

Well, I'm building a game which has 3 mode, vs computer, vs another player on same machine and vs another player on the network.
so what i want to do is:

if vs computer:

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, computer ai)
```

if vs sameMachine:

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, player2 player2)
```

if vs overNetwork:

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, networkPlayer nPlayer)
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: There is this magical thing called the [if statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)...

Comment: Add logic inside constructor !

Comment: @LyesCHIOUKH well all i'm asking for is the definition of the constructor, if i wrote ClassConstructor(player c, network n), it would ask for objects of those two classes only in if conditions. so how to make the constructor general?

Answer (score 1):

If `player1`, `player2` and `computer` implement a common interface, the constructor can be made even more general than what you're asking for.

```
ClassConstructor(Agent agent1, Agent agent2)
```

where `Agent` is the common interface (or base class) of the other types

Answer (score 0):

The player1, player2, computer can extend from same base class Player.
You can write only one constracter,and new different objects.

Answer (score 0):

if vs computer:

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, computer ai)
```

if vs sameMachine:

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, player2 player2)
```

if vs overNetwork:

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, networkPlayer nPlayer)
```

**Constructor**

```
ClassConstructor(player1 player1, Object obj){
    if (obj instanceof computer) {
    //your code
    }
    if (obj instanceof networkPlayer) {
    //your code
    }
    if (obj instanceof player) {
    //your code
    }
}
```